# Clojure: summing values in a collection of maps

Tags: collections, clojure, maps, sum, reduce

I am trying to sum up values of a collection of maps by their common keys. I have this snippet:

```
(def data [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}]
(for [xs data] (map xs [:a :b]))
((1 2) (1 2))

Final result should be ==> (2 4)
```

Basically, I have a list of maps. Then I perform a list of comprehension to take only the keys I need.

My question now is how can I now sum up those values? I tried to use "reduce" but it works only over sequences, not over collections.

Thanks.

===EDIT====

Using the suggestion from Joost I came out with this:

```
(apply merge-with + (for [x data] (select-keys x [:col0 :col1 :col2]))
```

This iterates a collection and sums on the chosen keys. The "select-keys" part I added is needed especially to avoid to get in trouble when the maps in the collection contain literals and not only numbers.

Answer (score 11):

If you really want to sum the values of the common keys you can do the whole transformation in one step:

```
(apply merge-with + data)
=> {:a 2, :b 4, :c 6}
```

To sum the sub sequences you have:

```
(apply map + '((1 2) (1 2)))
=> (2 4)
```

Comment: your implementation with merge-with is really cool. Would you also have a suggestion on how to apply this to specific keys? Otherwise it will not work when maps have literals.

Comment: you mean literals other than numbers?

Comment: Yes, but I think came up with a solution, I wrote it in my first post.