# Clojure: I have many sorted maps and want to reduce in order all there values a super maps of keys -> vector

Tags: data-structures, clojure, sortedmap

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927899/clojure-summing-values-in-a-collection-of-maps) but can't work out how to apply it (no pun intended) to my situation.

I have a sorted list of maps like this: (note there can be more than two keys in the map)
({name1 3, name2 7}, {name1 35, name2 7}, {name1 0, name2 3})

What I am after is this data structure afterwards:

({:name1 [3,35,0]}, {:name2 [7,7,3]})

Ive been struggling with this for a while and cant seem to get anywhere near.

Caveats:  The data must stay sorted and I have N keywords not just two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for `merge-with` with some preprocessing added:

```
(def maps [{:a :b :e :f} {:a :c} {:a :d :e :g}])
(apply merge-with concat (for [m maps [k v] m] {k [v]}))
>>> {:e (:f :g), :a (:b :c :d)}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use case.  I just passed my maps function in place of maps in the function.  One day I might be able to work this out for myself purely functionly :)

Comment: @AlexForeman Well, this *is* purely functional as in "no side effects". If you mean an elegant composition of library functions, I tried to find one but whatever I managed to stitch was longer and less readable than the above solution.

Comment: Ahh no what I meant is that currently after having done OO for so many years my brain sees the solution in OO and im having a hard time learning to think functionally, and mapping the solution.  Thus why I am learning Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you want is merge-with:

```
user=> (def x {:a 1 :b 2})
user=> (def y {:a 3 :b 4})
user=> (merge-with vector x y)
{:a [1 3], :b [2 4]}
user=> 
user=> (def z {:a 5 :b 6 :c 7})
user=> (merge-with vector x y z)
{:a [[1 3] 5], :c 7, :b [[2 4] 6]} ; oops
user=> (merge-with #(vec (flatten (vector %1 %2))) x y z)
{:a [1 3 5] :b [2 4 6] :c 7}
user=>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at the problem. It is not as elegant as Rafal's solution.

```
(def maps [{:a :b :e :f} {:a :c} {:a :d :e :g}])
(apply merge-with #(if (list? %1) (conj %1 %2) (list %1 %2)) maps)
>>> {:a (:d :b :c), :e (:f :g)}
```