# Clojure: summing values in a collection of maps until a value is reached.

Tags: collections, clojure, maps

My goal is to add up values in a collection of maps until a value is reached in one of the map values. I tried figuring it out using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927899/clojure-summing-values-in-a-collection-of-maps)  but it didn't touch on how I could only grab part of the list.  Then return the collection without the values that went over. Something like this

```
(def foo '({:key 1, :value 2} {:key 1, :value 2} {:key 1, :value 2})
(defn addValuesUp [foo]
  (take-while (< ((apply merge-with + foo) :value) 4) foo))
 and have it return something like this
'({:key 1, :value 2} {:key 1, :value 2})
```

Instead I get an error Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I will solve the problem will be by adding to the maps a new key with the accumulation of all the previous values so you can do a simple take-while:

```
(defn sums-of-values [c]
  (reductions + c))

(defn with-accum [c]
  (map #(assoc %1 :accum %2)
       c
       (sums-of-values (map :value c))))
```

Now that the maps have a :accum slot, you can use take-while:

```
(take-while (comp (partial >= 4)
                  :accum)
            (with-accum foo))
```

Comment: Thank you this worked for me I also added another function containing 
  (apply merge-with + foo) afterwards which added up all the values

Comment: Note that the last value out of the take-while already has the total in the :accum slot

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation for `take-while`:

```
clojure.core/take-while
([pred coll])
  Returns a lazy sequence of successive items from coll while
  (pred item) returns true. pred must be free of side-effects.
```

`pred` in this case is a function that returns a boolean. In your code, your first argument to `take-while` is not a function but an expression instead.

This is why you get the error `ClassCastException java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn`. This error is telling you that where Clojure expects a function (IFn) but it found a boolean (the result of your expression).

Once you turn that into a function, you should make progress. Some more work might be required in the function implementation however.

Comment: This makes sense to me but I cannot figure out how to make a function that will iterate with the take-while function to return a boolean.